# Reasonable OneNote alternative for Android

Tags: microsoft-onenote, ms-office

I just wanted to know if there's a OneNote app for Android, that would allow me to actually use it to its full potential (unlike that crap released by MS).

I am thinking about getting a Transformer and it is very important to me since all my notes from classes and lectures are in OneNote. I found many apps that would allow me to work with Word, Excel or PowerPoint. But everybody seems to be forgetting about OneNote...

Comment: What's wrong with the official?

Comment: It lacks .. everything. I need the equation editor, tags, text formatting, charts, tables, customizable shortcuts (via AutoCorrect). The official only allows me to view already done notes and change bold, italic or underline and can do 2 types of lists. Not good enough to take notes

Comment: You should add that information to your question. As it stands, this question isn't a good fit for this site. Questions that "ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" are what works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneNote for Android?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.onenote&hl=en

hope I got you right - as my answer is... well... just tooooo obvious :)

Comment: You didn't. Quote from the question: "unlike that crap released by MS" the one you linked is the one described as crap.

Answer (score 4):

## [Evernote](http://evernote.com/)

I consider [Evernote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote) to be the closest alternative to OneNote, available from [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote).

For me, the biggest advantage of Evernote, which even OneNote doesn’t have, is the synchronization feature.

### Key Features:

> - Sync all of your notes across the computers and devices you use
> - Create and edit text notes, to-dos and task lists
> - Save, sync and share files
> - Search for text inside images
> - Organize notes by notebooks and tags
> - Email notes and save tweets to your Evernote account
> - Connect Evernote to other apps and products you use
> - Share notes with friends and colleagues via Facebook and Twitter

#### Screen Shots (Android):

[image: Evernote Screen Shots]

Comment: While I'm an Evernote user myself, it's really lacking in terms of note content. It doesn't have any of the feature that the OP lists in the comments.

Comment: @RichardBorcsik Hence why I said "closest alternative" ;) What the OP needs seems like a full Office Solution inside a Post-It application!

Comment: OneNote does have synchronization feature...

Comment: @SachinShekhar My bad, I don't use OneNote for a long time now... EverNote came along and throw it to the "box in the garage"! I'll provide an update to the answer. tks :)

Comment: I used Evernote for some time myself. While it is an ok app for casual notes, such as shopping list, todos and similar, it can't work as a paper replacement, in terms of taking notes in classes. Thanks, though

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old discussion but so far the closest one I found (that nobody apparently knows yet) is Fiinote https://www.fiinote.com/#/

supports Android, Windows, there is an online HTML5 version, cloud sync, can write anywhere and move it, supports image attachment

I dare say that this has most of onenote's functionality we love and know on android even better than what Microsoft has provided!
BUT it is very cluttered and may be a mess for some who prefer OneNote clean look.
(that is kinda what is expected if you have the desktop OneNote client crammed into a 4.5 inch Android screen but it does the job pretty well so far and sync on all devices perfectly.)

I really hope OneNote team take a closer look at this software and make their Android version editable just like their awesome desktop version does beautifully!